# What is the equivalent to InnerText in LINQ-to-XML?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

My XML is:

```
<CurrentWeather>
  <Location>Berlin</Location>
</CurrentWeather>
```

I want the string "Berlin", how do get contents out of the element **Location**, something like **InnerText**?

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
string location = xdoc.Descendants("Location").ToString();
```

the above returns

> System.Xml.Linq.XContainer+d__a

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For your particular sample:

```
string result = xdoc.Descendants("Location").Single().Value;
```

However, note that Descendants can return multiple results if you had a larger XML sample:

```
<root>
 <CurrentWeather>
  <Location>Berlin</Location>
 </CurrentWeather>
 <CurrentWeather>
  <Location>Florida</Location>
 </CurrentWeather>
</root>
```

The code for the above would change to:

```
foreach (XElement element in xdoc.Descendants("Location"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.Value);
}
```

Comment: I had tried that and was getting an error on Single(), turned out I had "using System.Xml.Linq" but forgot "using System.Linq", thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
public static string InnerText(this XElement el)
{
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (XNode element in el.DescendantNodes().Where(x=>x.NodeType==XmlNodeType.Text))
    {
        str.Append(element.ToString());
    }
    return str.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string location = doc.Descendants("Location").Single().Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string location = (string)xdoc.Root.Element("Location");
```

Answer (score 0):

In a simple case with the single element,

```
<CurrentWeather>
   <Location>Berlin</Location>
</CurrentWeather>

string location = xDocument..Descendants("CurrentWeather").Element("Location").Value;
```

Multiple elements like this,

```
<CurrentWeather>
    <Location>Berlin</Location>
    <Location>Auckland</Location>
   <Location>Wellington</Location>
</CurrentWeather>

  foreach (var result in xDocument.Descendants("CurrentWeather").Select(x => new{ location = x.Element("Location").Value.Tostring() }))
        {
          Locations + = location ;
        }
```